# Не настраивается fancybox

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, в нем настройки прописаны(я его скопировал из гайда и подстроил под свой код). Теперь когда я хочу добавить настройку из общий настроек fancybox, например showNavArrays, скрипт вообще перестает работать, было бы ясно если бы не работала только эта команда а так он полностью не работает потом. Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.gallery, a.iframe").fancybox();

  $("a.gallery").fancybox({
    "padding": 0, // отступ контента от краев окна
    "imageScale": true, // Принимает значение true - контент(изображения) масштабируется по размеру окна, или false - окно вытягивается по размеру контента. По умолчанию - TRUE
    "zoomOpacity": true, // изменение прозрачности контента во время анимации (по умолчанию false)
    "zoomSpeedIn": 0, // скорость анимации в мс при увеличении фото (по умолчанию 0)
    "zoomSpeedOut": 0, // скорость анимации в мс при уменьшении фото (по умолчанию 0)
    "zoomSpeedChange": 2000, // скорость анимации в мс при смене фото (по умолчанию 0)
    "frameWidth": 100, // ширина окна, px (425px - по умолчанию)
    "frameHeight": 150, // высота окна, px(355px - по умолчанию)
    "overlayShow": true, // если true затеняят страницу под всплывающим окном. (по умолчанию true). Цвет задается в jquery.fancybox.css - div#fancy_overlay 
    "overlayOpacity": 0.9, // Прозрачность затенения  (0.3 по умолчанию)
    "hideOnContentClick": false, // Если TRUE  закрывает окно по клику по любой его точке (кроме элементов навигации). Поумолчанию TRUE  
    "centerOnScroll": false // Если TRUE окно центрируется на экране, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу
    showNavArrays: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: Зачем вам такие древние версии `jquery` и `fancybox`?

Comment: древние?) я их совсем недавно скачал, думал это последние версии))
оно не работает из-за того чтчо версия старая или есть ещё кое что о чем я не знаю?)

Comment: Откройте консоль в браузере и посмотрите есть ли там сообщения об ошибках и что пишет. Текущий fansybox смотрите тут http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 1):

Запятой после последнего `false` не хватает, вот в этой строчке:

```
"centerOnScroll": false
```